# Auto-populate a cell based on text input of one cell and the presence of text in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I'm trying to reduce the amount of manual input on a Drawing Log I'm presently creating.

Basically, I've got 5 columns: Drawing No., Client, Project, Date, and Description (in that order, though Date isn't important for this). The Drawing No. and Client is consistent for a single project (all following logged drawings for that project just includes a suffix for the Drawing No.)

Here's a screenshot with some example values Spaced columns because *aesthetic*.

[image]

Anyway, more importantly, what I am trying to achieve:

I would like to be able to just type in the name of the project ("Proj. 1" in this case) and, provided it already has an entry logged, auto-fill the Drawing No. and Client cells with their respective contents ("AB-10001" and "Joe" in this case). But, to avoid auto-filling a cell with a suffixed value, I'd want it to "look for" the respective row with "Project Start" listed in the description and use the Drawing No. from that row, as that's the raw vanilla number.

In my bones I feel like I'm going to need a VLOOKUP function with some other functions sprinkled in, but with my "self-taught" knowledge I don't know how I'd implement this. I'm versed more-so in number-based formulas.

[EDIT: I'm going to reiterate my query here and try and boil it down, as 'feeling' I need a VLOOKUP-type function has probably thrown us off a bit - I'm trying to create something more akin to Google's Autofill. I.e. I type in a project, if it's already in the log somewhere then it fills the neighbouring cells with the related information, otherwise it remains untouched]

Any and all help will be appreciated. Alternative methods also appreciated - Pretend I'm along for the ride.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look here for how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Comment: I would use the FILTER method

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the response, though I'm not sure how I can relate this to my particular cells - Probably my mistake in feeling I need a VLOOKUP-type function. That's likely skewed my perceived intentions here - Shows what I know.

I think I should reiterate my query a bit - I need something that behaves less like a search box and something more akin to Google's Autofill, if you know what I mean